# Модальное окно при клике на элемент , взятый из json

Tags: javascript, html, json

уважаемые форумчане .Помогите реализовать открытие самого простого модального окна по клику на конкретного пользователя c более детальной информацией, взятой из json (например sreet, city, zipcode и т.п.). Вот сама таблица `

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test task</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="t-header" data-prop="name" data-sort="asc">Name</th>
        <th class="t-header" data-prop="username" data-sort="asc">Username</th>
        <th class="t-header" data-prop="email" data-sort="asc">Email</th>
        <th class="t-header" data-prop="website" data-sort="asc">Website</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="users-table-body"></tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Не знаю как реализовать клик на конкретного пользователя.

```
(async () => {
async function getUsers() {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
    return response.data;
}

function render(users) {
    const tableBody = document.getElementById('users-table-body');
    tableBody.innerHTML = users.reduce((html, user) =>
        html + `
        <tr>
            <td>${user.name}</td>
            <td>${user.username}</td>
            <td>${user.email}</td>
            <td>${user.phone}</td>
        </tr>`, '');
}

let users = await getUsers();
render(users);

document.querySelector('thead tr')
    .addEventListener('click', e => {
        const tag = e.target;
        if (tag.classList.contains('t-header')) {
            const property = tag.getAttribute('data-prop');
            users = users.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a[property] > b[property]) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (a[property] < b[property]) {
                    return -1
                }
                return 0;
            });
            render(users);
            console.log(
                tag.getAttribute('data-prop'),
                tag.getAttribute('data-sort'))
        }
    })})();
```

Загрузка данных (пользователей) URL: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Без использования сторонних библиотек.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на этот пример, здесь мы после инициализации получаем все строки и перебирая их добавляем события клика, где, клик по строке ищет в исходном массиве пользователей по порядковому номеру строки данные и вставляет в html тела модального окна, вы можете вставить различные данные, я сделал для примера лишь имя, данные пример работает в случае если пользователи идут по порядку!

```js
let modal = document.querySelector("#modal");

(async() => {
  async function getUsers() {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`);
    return response.data;
  }

  function render(users) {
    const tableBody = document.getElementById('users-table-body');
    tableBody.innerHTML = users.reduce((html, user) =>
      html + `
        <tr>
            <td>${user.name}</td>
            <td>${user.username}</td>
            <td>${user.email}</td>
            <td>${user.phone}</td>
        </tr>`, '');
  }

  let users = await getUsers();
  render(users);

  let userRow = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');
  userRow.forEach(function(row, userId) {
    row.addEventListener('click', e => {
      let userData = users[users.findIndex(item => item.id === userId)];
      console.log(userData);
      document.getElementById('modal_body').innerHTML = userData.name;
      document.getElementById('modal').style.display='initial';
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: none;
}

#modal_body {
  margin-bottom: 1rem
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test task</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="t-header" data-prop="name" data-sort="asc">Name</th>
        <th class="t-header" data-prop="username" data-sort="asc">Username</th>
        <th class="t-header" data-prop="email" data-sort="asc">Email</th>
        <th class="t-header" data-prop="website" data-sort="asc">Website</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="users-table-body"></tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="modal" id="modal">
    <div id="modal_body"></div>
    <button class="class-button" id="close-button" onClick="document.getElementById('modal').style.display='none';">Закрыть</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>`
```

Comment: З.Ы. пример выполнения смотреть при развертывании **На всю страницу**